# Update to bound output VERY slow

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Google Maps autocomplete to provide a city search on a form.  It's instantiated by a jQuery docuemnt ready callback...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var autocompleteOptions = {
        types: ['(cities)']
    };
    var input = document.getElementById('locSearch');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, autocompleteOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        var searchScope = angular.element($("#search")).scope();
        searchScope.updateLoc({lat:place.geometry.location.lat(), lng:place.geometry.location.lng(), locName:place.formatted_address});
    });
});
```

As you can see, I'm looking up the scope of the form (probably breaking some sort of best practice) and calling a function in my controller...

```
$scope.updateLoc = function(newLoc) {
    $scope.currentSearch.config.loc = newLoc;
    $scope.updateLocLabel();
}

$scope.updateLocLabel = function() {
    if($scope.currentSearch.config.loc.distance == -1){
        $scope.locLabel = "Everywhere"; 
    }else{
        $scope.locLabel = "Within " + $scope.currentSearch.config.loc.distance + " miles of " + $scope.currentSearch.config.loc.locName.split(',')[0];
    }
}
```

This works just fine, except the bound label in my HTML as {{locLabel}} is taking upwards of 5 seconds to update!  Batarang is showing the longest watch expression as < 1ms.  I've done somewhat similar things in other places in my app, but I've never seen this kind of delay in the update to the DOM by Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember call `$scope.$apply` when you change scope variable outside angular.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var searchScope = angular.element($("#search")).scope();
    searchScope.updateLoc({lat:place.geometry.location.lat(), lng:place.geometry.location.lng(), locName:place.formatted_address});
    searchScope.$apply(); // add this line
});
```